# RecyclerView ViewHolder with swipe and undo like in gmail

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swipe, itemtouchhelper

I'm trying to make RecyclerView with swipes like in Gmail app.

I'm using:

- RecyclerView
- custom `ViewHolder`
- layout with content and swipe result (view with some solid background and text what action was applied, undo button) areas
- `ItemTouchHelper`
- `ItemTouchHelper.Callback`

Custom background is not a big deal, force `ItemTouchHelper.Callback` to move only content view also. The trick is to handle clicks on 'undo' button. While ViewHolder is in swiped out state, `ItemTouchHelper.Callback` handles every touches as swipe movements. How do I work around this issue? Is there another way to implement swipes?

Comment: I believe that, if you have a view on top your background you can set a click listener. If it doesn't work, how are you handles those swipes? (the code for it)

Comment: swipes are handled with ItemTouchHelper.Callback